How to fetch Tableau Server Tables with its fields and logics too if it's a calculated field?
I want to get list of all the tables in my tableau server along with the fields. If the field is a calculated field then I want to fetch its logic as well.
I have tried to use Metadata API, I can get table names and fields(columns) with that. Here is the graphQL query for that -
query q{
     tables{
        name
        columns{
          name
        }
      }
}

I don't think I am getting calculated fields from this, and I need the logic too.
I am stuck here for very long time, help please.
Thanks in advance!
